# Disable scrolling on content inset in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to create a complex view using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to do a profile view with two scroll views on top of each other. I created wireframes, so it's easier to understand.

[image: State 1]

Here you can see the red and blue rectangle. They are both scroll views. I'm trying to achieve that the blue rectangle must only be scrollable from its content (blue section) but must be able to cover the whole screen when we scroll on it. See the next two states:

[image: State 2] [image: State 3]

I tried adding some content inset using the library [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX), but can't seem to find a way to disable the scrolling mechanism on that content inset. So the red section of the wireframes must still be scrollable when scrolling on that area.

I tried only using drag gestures with offset, but the feeling was not as smooth as a scrolling view, and I could not mimic that feeling.

The default Apple implementation for a bottom sheet is not ideal because it works in steps, whereas I need it to be as smooth and controllable as a standard scroll view.

If any of you had any leads or ideas, it would be life-saving. I have spent hours on this and have been able to find a suitable solution.

Comment: This one can be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67891292/14733292